# Is it possible to add packages for "InternalsVisibleTo" at the command line or via a config file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-4.7

We have some methods that are `internal` but that people may need visible in test projects (and only test projects). To enable that, we had to add a bunch of `InternalsVisibleTo` statements at the top of a class. This is a library that may be used by many other projects and to help with testing and verification, we'd like to make the packages that can see the internals be settable at runtime.

Is this possible?

Example (Pseudo code):

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( System.ReadFromCommandLine("package"))]
```

Comment: Either you should make those methods public, or you should stub/mock them inside the tests of those other projects, is my opinion.

Comment: There should be a one-to-one correlation between a library and a test project for that library. Additionally, regardless of *where* you add `InternalsVisibleTo`, the entire contents of the library are made visible to the specified project, so adding this on top of every class makes no sense, i.e. you're not just exposing this one particular class. `InternalsVisibleTo` is an assembly directive. Long and short, you should only need to add this once, and there should really only be one project you add it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Attributes like `InternalsVisibleTo` must have their values be compile time constants.

> An expression `E` is an *attribute_argument_expression* if all of the following statements are true:
>
> - The type of `E` is an attribute parameter type (Attribute parameter types).
> - At **compile-time**, the value of `E` can be resolved to one of the following:
>
>   - A constant value.
>   - A `System.Type` object.
>   - A one-dimensional array of *attribute_argument_expression*s.

Boldface added, [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#attribute-specification).